# Android TMX library no tile animation

Tags: java, android

Did anyone use [this library](https://github.com/davidmi/Android-TMX-Loader)? I am wondering if this library has a possibility to display tile animation? When I try to show my "abc_main.tmx" map (created in Tiled application) the tile with animation just stays still. How to solve that AND the most importantly is it possible with this library? I am such desperate to have working tile animations that I think about rewriting my whole game into libGDX project... But wouldn't be an exagerration and huge not neccesary work overhead in compare to finding a solution within library mentioned above?

Here is my code:

GameThread.java

```
    public class GameThread<T extends GameSurface> extends Thread {

private boolean isRunning;
private long startTime, loopTime;
private long delay = 33;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private T gameSurface;

public GameThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, T gameSurface)  {
    this.surfaceHolder= surfaceHolder;
    this.gameSurface = gameSurface;
    isRunning = true;
}

@Override
public void run()  {
    while(isRunning) {
        startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
        if(canvas != null) {
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            gameSurface.drawMapBitmap(canvas);
            (...)
}
```

GameMainSurface.java

```
    @Override
public void drawMapBitmap(Canvas canvas) {
    if (((ActivityGame) context).isDemo() && currentMap instanceof MapMain)
        canvas.drawBitmap(mapMainImageResizedLayer1, 0, 0, pt.pMap);

    (...)
}

    @Override
protected void initMaps() {
    TileMapData tileMainMapData = TmxLoader.readTMX("abc_main.tmx", context);
    int mapMainWidth = tileMainMapData.width;
    int mapMainHeight = tileMainMapData.height;
    Bitmap mapImageOrgLayer1 = TmxLoader.createBitmap(tileMainMapData, context, 0, 1);
    mapMainImageResizedLayer1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mapImageOrgLayer1, getCellWidth() * mapMainWidth, getCellHeight() * mapMainHeight, false);

  (...)

}
```